# here-api position centered svg icon on the Map

Tags: javascript, here-api

have a question for positioning icons on the here Map V3 with the Javascript framework in the Browser (Chrome, Firefox).

[position marker example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMBY8.png)

I create an svg arrow which is possible to rotate.
(green point and the rectangle are just for better recognizing the problem)
But I cannot center the new created Icon on an GeoCoordinate.
The green icon point and the arrow are positioned at the same GeoCoordinate.

I want that my Icon is exact centered on this GeoCoordinate, because if you have different zoom level the arrow seems to move away from the GeoCoordinate.

One of the code snippets I used

```
var svgArrow = '<svg width="30" height="30"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
                '<polyline points="15,2 25,27 15,15 5,27" stroke="#FE6940" fill="#FE6940" transform="rotate('+ PosDirection + ',15,15)"/> </svg>';
var iconSVG = new H.map.Icon(svgArrow);
addMarkerToGroup(iconGroup, {lat:Latitude, lng:Longitude},
            '', {icon:iconSVG});
```

I tried some things with additional css which should work told by other user, but nothing helps to get the correct position.
did anyone had an idea how to solve this issue.

Thanks allot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS styles have no effect in this case because the marker is rendered in the canvas, thus is not itself in the DOM tree.

However you can achieve what you need by specifying options to the `H.map.Icon` construction, more specifically using the property `anchor` which takes x and y offsets. Something like the following:

```
var iconSVG = new H.map.Icon(svgArrow, {
  anchor: {
    x: svgWidth / 2,
    y: svgHeight / 2
  }
});
```

Comment: Works exactly the way it has to. Thanks a lot Michael.